# How to avoid flickering in Main Form while try to hide and show the child forms

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

Requirement is show the child form by hiding the existing child in Main Form.

Its works fine but flickering rises in Main Form. Could please share some suggestion .

```
     void Form1Btn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {            
        var form2 = new Sample2Form();
        this.Hide();
        form2.ShowDialog(mainform);
    }
```

Comment: Of course it "flickers," you're hiding one form and showing another. The flicker is the hiding and reshowing. When something changes on the screen, it's going to flicker. What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the content to a `UserControl`. So you have a UserControl for every Form you have.

Then you create a root Form with a (root) Panel in it.

To display the created UserControl in the Form do something like that:

```
rootPanel.Controls.Add(yourUserControl);
```

When you now want to switch between the two UserControls you can replace the content of the rootPanel with the child UserControl:

```
rootPanel.Controls.Clear();
rootPanel.Controls.Add(yourChildControl);
```